# Как перемешивать только выбранные слова в тексте (python)?

Tags: python

Здравствуйте! 
 Необходимо найти и перемешать в тексте некоторые слова, например, hash и code, причём этих слов в тексте много. Как понимаю, сначала нужен ввод файла open("infile.txt",'r'), потом поиск избранных слов, объединение их в некий массив, перемешивание этого массива с помощью random.shuffle, запись этого массива на исходные местоположения в тексте и запись файла, наконец.  Помогите связать все элементы!

Спасибо ReinRaus ♦  и vinger4! Задача решена! Я добавил ввод-вывод файла для удобства.

```
   import re, random

regex= re.compile('hash|code') # что ищем
with open("C:\infile.txt",'r') as f:
    lines = f.read()
endpos=0
match= regex.search(lines,endpos)
matches=[] # массив с совпадениями
strings=[] # все остальное что не совпало, при этом если два совпадения подряд, или начало (конец) строки и совпадение, то в этот массив попадает пустая строка
    # поэтому значения в массивах чередуются относительно целевой строки
while (match):
 strings+= [ lines[endpos:match.start()] ]
 endpos= match.end()
 matches+=[match.group(0)]
 match= regex.search(lines,endpos)
if (endpos==len(lines)): strings+= [ "" ]
random.shuffle(matches)

result= "" # собираем строку обратно с перемешанными данными
for i in range(len(matches)):
 result+=strings[i]+matches[i]
result+=strings[-1]

with open("C:\Python27\outfile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(result)
```

Comment: может перемешивать не массив, а индексы позиций в исходном тексте?

Comment: спасибо за совет, я ближе к цели

Comment: напишите куски кода - посмотрим как они стыкуются

Comment: import re
f = open('infile.txt','r').read()
words = 'hash' , 'code'
for words in f:
     n = re.search(words)
random.shuffle(n)
with open("outfile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines()

Comment: Как-то так:  
http://ideone.com/9yPEgp  
Утром опубликую как ответ, если устраивает.

Comment: Спасибо!!!  Я добавил ввод-вывод файла для удобства.  Можете опубликовать как ответ!

Comment: не помещайте ответ в вопрос. [Опубликуйте Ваше решение как ответ (это даже приветствуется)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

какие ошибки при компиляции? пока вижу следующее:

```
import re
import random
f = open('infile.txt','r').read()
words = ['hash' , 'code'] # в следующей строке переменной будет присвоено другое значение - зачем тогда она тут?
for words in f:
    n = re.search(words) # ищем слова в строке?
    random.shuffle(n) # там же их перемешиваем? а если оно одно? наверное лучше сложить в отдельный словарь типа "индекс - слово"

with open("outfile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(lines) # какое значение у переменной lines?
```